# How to use css classes in Best way without redundant?

Tags: html, css

I had a email textbox with default,success,error css class.

```
<input id="emailInput" class="sansserif inputuser" style=" margin-top: 5px;" type="text" placeholder="Enter Email.."/>

.default{   
    width: 306px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color:  #737373;
    font-weight: 600;
    background-color: white;
    background-image: url('../Styles/Icons/User Male-35.png');
    background-position: 5px 5px; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
}

.error{ 
    width: 306px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 2px solid #ff0000;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color:  #737373;
    font-weight: 600;
    background-color: white;
    background-image: url('../Styles/Icons/User Male-35.png');
    background-position: 5px 5px; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;    
}

.success{ 
    width: 306px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 2px solid #00b33c;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color:  #737373;
    font-weight: 600;
    background-color: white;
    background-image: url('../Styles/Icons/User Male-35.png');
    background-position: 5px 5px; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;    
}
```

here i'm applying following css classes default ,error and success while validating email text box but only difference from the above three classes is **border** property only .how to reduce the redundant css properties is there any better way to achieve this.

Comment: you can apply styles to multiple classes by separating the classes with a comma. e.g. `.one , .two ` will affect the styles of any items with class 'one' or class 'two'

Comment: Use "inheritance" for objects... i.e. a CSS class `.email_textbox` with all the common info and the other classes (defined after the common one) with the changes.

Comment: make a common class for same css, and three different class for default success error and use it accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define similar css at one place with joining multiple selectors and overriding later if necessary:

***Note:*** The styles that you are overriding i.e for `.error` and `.success` must come after the generic styles otherwise they will be overridden by default styles and you won't see any change.

```
.default,
.error,
.success {   
  width: 306px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color:  #737373;
  font-weight: 600;
  background-color: white;
  background-image: url('../Styles/Icons/User Male-35.png');
  background-position: 5px 5px; 
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
}

.error { 
  border-color: #ff0000;
}

.success { 
  border-color: #00b33c;
}
```